# have multiple tables with the same key that are separated by type of data or keep things together in the single table

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I have broken up a very large database table into smaller, manageable, normalized tables.

But there is one exception to this. The tables in question are from a products database that stores information about products that the company sells. I have separated much of the information into two tables: `ProductBase` and `ProductBasePackaging`.

These tables hold the information that is relevant to a base part number rather than an individual product (there are multiple products to each base number).

`ProductBase` contains rather general information such as `MarketingCopy`, `Keywords` etc. and also information on construction i.e. material, components etc.

And `ProductBasePackaging` holds data about the packaging.

Maybe I have just made it harder on myself now that I have to keep track of multiple tables that use the same key (the base part number). Or maybe I am right to have separated them and maybe should have taken it a step further and separated the construction into its own table as well.

Should I have multiple tables with the same key that are separated by type of data or keep things together in the single table where I can reference everything I need using the same key?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I edited this post right before your comment & thought I had improved the title. But I had only improved the title of [the other question that I was editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3282510/revisions) whose title had been (despite titles supposedly being unique) the totally uninformative 'Database Normalization'. Title here updated from body now. (Maybe I was thrown by them both having score 7.)

Comment: @Nick (A) Not my down-vote. (B)  We write here on Stack Overflow for posterity. This site aims to be a knowledge base for future readers. That is why we should be motivated to edit our Questions and our Answers. And that is why I rarely check the age of a Question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normalization might look like a pain in the a** right now - but trust me, in the long run, you'll be **glad** you did it! Non-normalized "flat" tables with everything but the kitchen sink in them will become very unmanageable over time, data inconsistencies will creep in, and before you know it, you have a huge steaming pile of crap - errrg - data that doesn't make any sense anymore!

Yes, joining tables can be a bit of work - but especially for displaying data, you should definitely check out **views** which can help you write those JOINs once and then just use them as "virtual tables" that hold everything again.

Database normalization - up to roughly 3NF - is a *good thing* (TM) for sure! I would always recommend doing it, and then maybe at that point introduce back some limited de-normalization where performance needs might require it - but only in a very controlled way, and with your full understanding and knowledge that you are in fact denormalizing something again.

Comment: +1 I agree about **views**. OP should also keep in mind that querying `JOIN`ed tables can be much faster than one flat table if you have effectively de-duplicated.

Comment: +1. It sounds like the O.P. has got it about right. The products are individual widgets, right? But they get bundled into different SKUs for sale. Packages of 2,4,8,etc. Perhaps special house packaging for Walmart, etc. You've got (at least) two separate entities here.

Comment: @Nicholas yeah you have it right. But could you possibly elaborate on the separate entities in your example?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Marc. Views will definitely make it easier. It is a pain for sure, but I've done everything as best I can so far on this project so I might as well finish strong and do it right.

Comment: The *entity*, in an entity-relationship model, is a 'thing' (noun) that is important to the problem domain. The *relationships* in the model are verb phrases: they describe how the entities are tied to each other. The widget in my earlier comment is one such entity; 1 or more widgets, blister-packed on cardboard and ready to ship to a retailer is another such entity. And they've got a relationship (is contained in) that ties them together. The 2 entities have got different attributes and different relationships with other entities within the problem domain. Does that help?

Comment: @Nicholas yes it does thank you. This database structuring can be a lot to wrap your head around...

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **it depends**.

It depends on what you typically query, how you typically query, how often you query, how large the table is to hold all the data.... etc. **It depends.** 
An example of when you might **not** want to normalize would be if you need to query aggregated or derived data regularly and the process of compiling it takes a "long time."
*Usually* though I think data should be normalized.

That being said, I'm not sure what you described is "Normalization" as much as it's separation. Normalization would involve removing duplicated data in different columns.

Let's take your example of packaging... It seems to me like you've made a record in some `ProductBasePackaging` which is related by `PartNumber` to the `ProductBase` or something.

In reality, if you were normalizing the data... you'd have a `ProductBasePackaging` row only for each type of packaging... like maybe you ship 1000 different products but only use 10 different types of boxes.
`ProductBasePackaging` would have 10 rows, each having info on a unique box... then `ProductBase` would reference its required box by `PackagingID`

Comment: You are correct sir this is more separation than normalization that this question pertains to. The normalization I did was in the beginning when we had a massive table that had a ton of empty cells because of having things like "Thumb length" for an apron and repeating the same data over and over again for items in the same base part. 90% of the cells in the table were either empty or repeat data, it was gawd awful.